# Proof that a sequence cannot equal to zero for a certain range

Tags: sequences-and-series

$r$ is a real on the interval  $]0, \frac{π}{2}[$

let $f_n(t)=\frac{(r^2-t^2)^n}{2^nn!}$

and $I_n=\int_{0}^{r} f_n(t)cos(t) \,dt$

and $f_0(t)=1$

i have calculated $I_0$ and $I_1$

and proved the relation $(1)$ $I_n=(2n-1)I_{n-1}-r^2I_{n-2}$

$(*):$now let suppose that there exist $N$ such for all $n>N$:$I_n=0$

proof that $(*)$ is false using the values of $I_0$ and $I_1$ and the relation $(1)$

please help me with this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $I_n=0$ and $I_{n-1}=0$ then $I_{n-2}=0$ by (1). Use this to conclude that $I_n=0$ for all $n$. This  gives your contradiction since $I_0 \neq 0$.

Comment: is it possible to find a closed form for this sequence?

Comment: Closed form looks quite complicated. @ananadilwa3r